# Prove the monotonicity of $q\left(x\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)}{g\left(x\right)}$

Tags: calculus

Here has a function $q(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where

$$f(x)=\log_2\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1 x+b_1}\right),$$ $$g(x)=\log_2\left(1+\frac{1}{a_2 x+b_2}\right)$$ $$a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2 >0.$$

How to prove the monotonicity of $q(x)$? Since the first derivative is very complicated, it is difficult to analyze.

Comment: Am I to assume $x>0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Logarithms have the following property:

$$\frac{\log_ax}{\log_ay}=\log_yx$$

**Super Hint:** Show that

$$f(x) \text{ is monotone} \iff \exp(f(x)) \text{ is monotone}$$

Comment: Yes, thank you. Since y is a function of x rather than a constant, the monotonicity is still difficult to analyze.

Comment: See my super hint.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful hint. The monotonicity of $q\left(x\right)$ depends on the relationship among a1,  a2, b1, and b2.  I want to reveal the impact of these constants on monotonicity, but it seems hard because the first derivative is so complicated.